# Get active solution configuration name for pre-build event command line in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, configuration, msbuild

I have few configurations in my solution and I want to copy file ***app.`{my-own-configuration-name}`.config*** before building event.

I know about variable `$(Configuration)`, but this variable only contains `Debug` or `Release` names, not my solution configuration name. How can I achieve this?

[image]

```
The command "xcopy /Y "C:\xxx\config\App.Debug.config" "C:\xxx\App.config"" exited with code 2.
```

This should copy `App.Dev.config`, not `App.Debug.config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use "$(ConfigurationName)".

[image]

If it still doesn't work, you need to go to `Build > Configuration Manager`, then check if your project is under this configuartoin.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. `$(ConfigurationName)` was not working. Adding new configuration for projects in Configuration Manager window works (I'm still using `$(Configuration)`)

Comment: What if my active solution configuration is `DEV1` but my project configuration is `DEV2`? How can I retrieve them both?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Slow Cheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms).  It will help with transforming config files to the build configuration.

Looking at your copy command, the C:\...\ is an invalid path. Maybe you need $(SolutionDir)?

Comment: Path is OK - I just deleted all folders for this question

Comment: About Slow Cheetah - I'm looking for CI/CD solution for Azure DevOps Pipelines, so plugins for Visual Studio won't help me

Comment: We use Slow Cheetah in a MS Devops environment - It is part of the build process and gets transformed in the build pipeline and then the Artifact is created with the correct config file.  It is a  plugin for VS to transform the config file on build.